# CorePlot - Expected Token Before '@' token

Tags: xcode, expression, core-plot

I am trying to incorporate CorePlot into my project.  I finally manages to get my header files recognized but i keep getting the following error in my main.m.

"Expected expression before '@' token"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    @autoreleasepool { 
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ProjectFiveAppDelegate     class]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The @autoreleasepool syntax was introduced fairly recently, you probably need to install Xcode 4.2. Another possibility is that your compiler is set to GCC which AFAIK doesn't support those newer Objective-C changes.

If this is the only place where newer Objective-C extensions are used, you can simply change it to

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain( ...
[pool release];
return retVal;
```

Comment: Thanks Caffeine!  THat did the trick.  I was actually running Xcode Version 4.2 (Build 4C199).  THis has saved me so much time!

Comment: Thanks for the detail about the GCC compiler.  I left the @autoreleasepool syntax and changed the compiler from GCC LLVM 4.2 to Apple LLVM 4.1 and that also resolved the issue.