# Expected expression before '@' token main.m

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, admob, adwhirl

I added a `GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.1.4` SDK to my cocos2d app in order to integrate AdWhirl. When I added this Google SDK I got the following error:

> Expected expression before '@' token main.m

This is the code looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,
                                 NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your entire main method here?

Comment: At any rate, you ate a finishing }.

Comment: The original code does have that extra }.

Comment: The error refers to a file called `main.m`, it isn't necessarily referring to your `main` function.

Comment: I added all the frameworks necessary to AdMob. I know it happens every time I implement the sdk file into my app. Once I delete it the errors go away.

Comment: If you do not post the requested stuff, you will not get the help you need.  Errors usually have line numbers.  Post the entire error.  Also, as requested, post your main.m file, at least up to the line that contains the error.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using, and did you enable ARC?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue..
Xcode Version 4.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you're using a version of XCode that is 4.2 or above? I think `@autoreleasepool` is a newer syntax. This also won't work if your compiler is set to GCC. You can also just create your own `NSAutoreleasePool` using the old syntax if none of this works.

You can look at another answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553278/coreplot-expected-token-before-token).

Comment: I am using 4.4.1... I contacted AdWhirl and they stated that the new AdMob SDK is not supported by them.

Comment: anymore..... It used to be with their older SDK. I know that there is a way but I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried just changing the syntax for your autorelease pool's declaration as stated at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553278/coreplot-expected-token-before-token?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need add Add-ons folder from Google ad sdk.